# Resizing an array inside of an object in VBScript

Tags: arrays, vbscript

In VB script, I'm trying to resize an array inside of an object (named itemList()). ReDim works for normal arrays, but I get an error when resizing an array inside of an object. I'm trying to imitate a struct, so my goal is to have some type of object/struct that has a dynamic array inside..

```
Class Person
    Public name
    Dim itemList()
End Class 

Set person1 = new Person
person1.itemList(0) = "football"    'Works fine
ReDim person1.itemList(7)           'Error: "Expected "("
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot resize member variables of an object that way. A better approach to handling a list of items is to initialize the member variable as an empty array and append to it:

```
Class Person
    Public name
    Public itemList

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        itemList = Array()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Take(item)
        ReDim Preserve itemList(UBound(itemList)+1)
        itemList(UBound(itemList)) = item
    End Sub
End Class 

Set person1 = new Person
person1.Take "football"
```